# C++ строки помочь

Tags: c++

задание:

> требуется написать на С++ программу для ввода с клавиатуры текстовой
>   информации в файл на диск C:

программа открывается записывает уже заранее введенный текст.
а надо чтобы я в консоль из клавиатуры ввожу текст свой а потом уже идет сохранение на диск C:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(0,""); // включаем кириллицу в консоли
char * fileName = "C:\\example.txt"; // Путь к файлу для записи
FILE * file = fopen(fileName, "w");
if (file) // если есть доступ к файлу,
{
char * str = "I Like The Coding!"; // инициализируем строку
bool result = fputs(str, file); // и записываем ее в файл
if (!result) // если запись произошла успешно
cout << "Строка в файл успешно записана!" << endl; // выводим сообщение
}
else
cout << "Нет доступа к файлу!" << endl;
fclose(file);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Имеется несколько способов чтения строк из входного потока. Если писать программу, используя средства языка C, то вы можете считывать данные с консоли с помощью функции `fgets`.

Вот простая демонстрационная программа

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() 
{
    char s[BUFSIZ];

    while ( std::fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) )
    {
        fputs( s, stdout );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Если же писать программу, используя средства C++, то лучше всего воспользоваться  классом `std::string`  и соответствующей функцией `std::getline`, Вот демонстрационная программа для данного подхода

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;

    while ( std::getline( std::cin, s ) )
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В обоих программах вместо вывода строк на консоль, вам надо будет их отправлять в файл.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Настройка ввода данных в консоль.
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    //Создание массивов и настройка вывода в файл. 
    ofstream fout("text.txt");
    const int n = 1000;
    char str[n];
    gets_s(str);
    cout << str << endl;
    fout << str << endl;
    fout.close();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Можно и так попробовать. Уже записывая результат в файл. Это пример.